# Grails Dynamic radio group

Tags: grails, radio-group

I have a requirement for a grails application to display a list of questions on the screen with 6 grade options listed below each of the questions.  The information for these questions and grades is coming from a lookup table in the database. I have the questions and grades displaying on the screen but I'm not sure how to go about getting the lookup information to save in the database.  I would also like to know if there is a way to have a certain grade selected by default for each of the questions.  I tried the checked="S" but this only selects the S grade for the very bottom questions.

My code for the view is

```
  <label for="questions"></label>
    <ul class="one-to-many">
    <!-- Evaluation Questions -->
    <g:each in="${cdeEvaluationInstance?.questions}" var="evalQuestion" status="i">
    <g:hiddenField name="cdeEvaluation.questions[${i}].id" value="${evalQuestion.id}"/>
    <legend>
    ${evalQuestion.areaOfEval.title}
    </legend>
    <p>
    <strong>Focus areas: ${evalQuestion.areaOfEval.focusArea}</strong>
    </p>
    <p>
    <em> ${evalQuestion.areaOfEval.description}
    </em>
    </p>
    <p>
    <g:each in="${evalQuestion.areaOfEval.grades.sort{it.grade}}"
    var="grade" ><div class="radio">
    <span class="clear long"> 
    <input type="radio"
    name="radioGroup" value="${evalQuestion.grade}" checked="S"  /> 
    <label class="long"><strong> ${grade.grade}
    </strong> ${grade.description}</label>
    </div>
    </g:each>
```

My code for the controller is

```
def evalQuestions = EvaluationService.fetchActiveEvaluationQuestions();
            //def evaluation = new CdeEvaluation(questions: evalQuestions)

           def evaluation = new CdeEvaluation(params)
           evaluation.setQuestions(evalQuestions)
```

My domain for the table that the questions and answers are

```
package gov.mt.mdt.cde.domain.evaluation

import java.util.Date;

class CdeEvalQuestion extends Base{

    CdeAreaOfEvaluation areaOfEval
    CdeAreaOfEvalCriteria grade

    String comments

    static belongsTo = [cdeEvaluation: CdeEvaluation]




    static mapping = {
        id column: 'cevqu_id_seq'
        id generator: 'sequence', params: [sequence: 'cevqu_id_seq']

        areaOfEval column: 'caoe_id_seq'
        grade column: 'caoec_id_seq'
    }

    static constraints = {
        comments(blank:true, nullable:true, maxSize:2000)

        createdBy(blank: false, nullable:false, maxSize:13)
        dateCreated(blank: false, nullable:false)
        lastUpdatedBy(blank: false, nullable:true, maxSize:13)
        lastUpdated(blank: false, nullable:true)
    }
}
```

I am just starting to learn grails/groovy so any help or examples you could point me to would be great.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So selecting a particular question by default you would do something like:

```
<g:radioGroup name="myGroup" labels="evalQuestion.areaOfEval.grades" values="evalQuestion.areaOfEval.grades*.grade" value="evalQuestion.grade">
    ${it.radio} <label class="long"><strong>${it.label.grade}</strong> ${it.label.description}</label>
</g:radioGroup>
```

That doesn't require you write the inner each.  Basically you pass an array of labels and a parallel array of values.  The value attribute is the default value from the values attribute.  The inner body of the radioGroup will be repeated for each label and value pair.  The *. (aka spread operator) basically is the same thing as using the collect() method.

I removed the spread operator for label and I passed the full object in for the label.  Then inside the body of the tag when I do `it.label` I have the full object and can use different fields `it.label.description` and `it.label.grade`.

As for setting the default to grade S.  You'll need to write the code to find grade S from `evalQuestion.areaOfEval.grades`.  Something like:

```
evalQuestion.areaOfEval.grades.find { it.grade == 'S' }
```

And pass that to value attribute of the tag.  You could do this:

```
<g:set var="defaultGrade" value="evalQuestion.areaOfEval.grades.find { it.grade == 'S' }"/>

<g:radioGroup name="myGroup" 
              labels="evalQuestion.areaOfEval.grades" 
              values="evalQuestion.areaOfEval.grades*.grade" 
              value="defaultGrade">
```

Comment: I got it switched over and working but I have a question about 2 things. In the value field how would I default to select grade of 'S' which comes from evalQuestion.areaOfEval.grades?  Also in the first example you will notice that I have a strong tag around the grade letter. Is there a way to get that with the above example.  I seem to get the strong tag around all of the value or none.

Comment: Since I can't see into your domain model I'll try and answer your question.  I'll modify my question since comments are limited.

Comment: The label works great now.  Thank you!  I am still having problems with the default value though.  what is the -> in the code listed above supposed to do?  It will error out on my quote not closed when I use the syntax above.  I have tried a variety of other .find options without the -> and it doesn't work either.  Thanks for all your help...I really appreciate it!

Comment: I updated it to remove the use of -> for defining the Closure's parameter list.  Instead it uses the implied it variable that Closures with a single parameter can use.  If you want to understand what it means you'll need to read up on groovy closures.